# What are BinOps?

Tags: python, c, numpy

Going through NumPy's source code, I found a file called [binop_override.h](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/common/binop_override.h) talking about something called `binops`. I haven't come across the term before and to the best of my knowledge, a question asking about binops hasn't been asked on StackOverflow. I tried googling the matter, and I just got links to some open source libraries that use `binops`.

In layman's terms, what are BinOps and why are they used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's short for "binary operators". Binary operators are operators with two operands. These include:

- addition (`a + b`)
- concatenation (`a + b`)
- equality comparison (`a == b`)
- logical-AND (`a and b`)
- bitwise-AND (`a & b`)
- assignment (`a := b`)
- set membership (`a in b`)
- etc.

Binary operators are usually infix operators, meaning the operator is found between the operands. The subscription operator (`a[b]`) would be a binary operator that's not an infix operator.

---

Languages usually have a number unary operators (operators with a single operand) as well.

- numerical negation (`-a`)
- logical negation (`not a`)
- bitwise negation (`~a`)

---

Many have a ternary operator (an operator with three operands) called the conditional operator (`a ? b : c` in C).

Answer (score 1):

BinOp is a binary operation (like addition or division):

```
print(ast.dump(ast.parse('x + y', mode='eval'), indent=4))
Expression(
    body=BinOp(
        left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
        op=Add(),
        right=Name(id='y', ctx=Load())))
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html